# PayPal Billing and webhooks

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

Anyone who knows what webhook event will be triggered when paypal renews a billing-agreement: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-types ?

Their documentation is pretty weak.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. We keep on improving the documentation from user feedback. Please feel free to share more. :)

Also, regarding Billing Agreement, there is no event associated with Billing Agreement supported by us yet. Please keep an eye on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-types as we release new events in next few weeks/months.